# forbid to cache resources from specific host

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-cache

Here is a problem. I am writing front-end application which heavily depends on JS.
To test it I have to refresh a webpage over and over again.
Because chrome caches every resources I have to clear cache every time.

Is there a way to tell browser not to cache JS files from specific domain at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Cache-Control: no-cache` HTTP header for the said resources (you have to specify this in your HTTP server config, though, but it is far easier to do once.)

You can also use the Chrome Developer Tools' "Disable cache" feature (found in the `General` section of the Settings pane, brought up by clicking the Gear button in the bottom right corner) for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = Math.random().toString().substr(2)
var url = '/some.js?' + a
```

In this case, url will be treated as a new resource every time, and will not be taken from cache. I hope you can do the rest on your own ;)